# How do I make this into a relational database on VB2010 and show it in a DataGridView?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm pretty new to using Visual Basic. I'm making a stock control program for the art department in my school and so far we've only covered the literal basics of coding.

I'm trying to put my database into a DataGridView on the main form of the program.

These are the tables of the database I want to use (I think it's normalised):

---

Stock (**StockID**, StockDescription, StockQuantity)

Supplier (**SupplierID**, SupplierName, SupplierPhone)

Brand (**BrandID**, BrandName)

Stock/Supplier (**StockID**, **SupplierID**)

Supplier/Brand (**SupplierID**, **BrandID**)

Category (**CategoryID**, CategoryDescription)

Subcategory (**StockID**, **SubcategoryID**, SubcategoryDescription)

Category/Subcategory (**CategoryID**, **SubcategoryID**)

---

The ones in bold are the keys I'm using for each table.
I'd like to know how to set this up as a relational database in VB and then how I would then go about putting it all into one DataGridView as one table, if that is possible. I understand that I might have to use inner joins?

Sorry if I'm missing anything completely obvious but like I said, I don't know a lot at all.

Comment: You are asking for far more here than could be covered in one SO answer but I will start you off with one key fact: there is no facility to put this into a relational database in VB itself; instead you use a database back end such as Access, MySQL, or (my recommendation ) MS SQL Server Express to create the database. You then write a program which 'talks to' the database system. But they are two separate parts, and very often are on two separate machines.

Comment: Im using Access at the moment

Comment: OK then in that case in order to get any help from SO you should show what you have tried and ask something much more specific. There's also lots of resources out there on the web, and in book form too. Try googling 'ADO.net Access'